# Any practical reason for using `var` over 'let`?

Tags: javascript

With ES6, I've stated using `let` keyword, instead of `var`.

Recently, in one of my code base, I didn't find any issue with removing `var` with `let` in 10000+ lines of code.

I know the difference between `var` and `let`, but **is there any practical reason where we should prefer `var` over `let`?**.

Comment: Backwards compatibility.

Comment: Read [this](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274342/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-var-keyword-in-es6).

Comment: Check this: [Is there any reason to use the “var” keyword in ES6?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274342/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-var-keyword-in-es6)

Comment: You said `I know the difference between var' and 'let`, then you said `but is there any practical reason where we should prefer 'var' over 'let'` you seem to be contradicting yourself

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: You've said you're using `let` everywhere now instead of `var`. Consider using `const` when you can -- which is surprisingly often.

Comment: I find it useful as a shorthand in variable initialization: `if (a) {var b = ...} ... if (b) { doStuff(); }`. This avoids the awkward-looking split declaration and initialization: `let b; if (a) {b = ...} ... if (b) { ... }`.